# Where does the term 'steam cockpit' come from?

Tags: flight-instruments, cockpit, terminology

Why are traditional style cockpits with gauges called 'steam cockpits'? Do the instruments actually run on steam?

Comment: The term is actually "steam gauges" - I've never heard anybody refer to a "steam cockpit".

Comment: I think it's simply because glass dial gauges resemble steam pressure gauges (e.g. on a steam engine, turbine, whatever). Certainly no aviation instruments have ever run on steam that I'm aware of.

Comment: @dvnrrs well, there *is* steampunk, but they usually prefer airships ;-)

Comment: I was a C130 Navigator and rode on them for about 25 years (the pilots drove me to work) and never really flew with a true glass cockpit, but....I never heard the gauges we used (and they had pointers/calibrated scale/and were round} referred to as "steam gauges" but reading the comments maybe I didn't pay it enough attention? Oh well, we always got to where we where going.

Comment: I don't know about the instruments, but the *engine* of at least one airplane [ran on steam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_Air_2000#Steam-powered).

Comment: Well, some flight _simulators_ probably run on [Steam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_(service))...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, to answer your second question first: no.  No aircraft instruments actually run on steam.  There are lots of safety issues related to generating and using the steam on board an aircraft that are prohibitive.

As far as why they are called ***steam gauges***, take a look at one and compare it to a traditional flight instrument:

[image: Steam Gauge] [image: Airspeed Indicator]

They are both round, both have a calibrated scale printed on  them, and both have a needle which points at the current value.  They actually look pretty similar!

Comment: so is a car speedometer/tachometer also a steam gauge?

Comment: Heh, I always thought "steam gauges" referred to vacuum gyro-instruments (as they work the same way, only backwards, pulling air out rather than pushing steam in..)

Comment: @shortstheory I've never heard them called that, but aviation is a more technical field so maybe it arose from people who worked wih both, back in the early days.

Comment: @falstro Well,the airspeed indicator, the altimeter, and the VSI are not vacuum powered but are called steam gauges!

Comment: @Lnafziger Oh I'm sure you're right! I just thought it was interesting how much we just assume sometimes :)

Comment: @Lnafziger: They're called "vacuum gyro-instruments" because the instruments measure the outputs of a vacuum-powered gyro. In other words, the vacuum makes the gyro spin. The instruments that measure the gyro (attitude, heading) are not themselves directly measuring pressure, as opposed to the airspeed indicator and altimeter, which are examples of instrments that directly measure pressure (just like a steam gauge).

Answer (score 11):

I never heard the term "steam gauge" until there were glass cockpits - but maybe that is just me.  A "steam gauge airplane" is a mildly derogative term to indicate that the plane has instruments that are old fashioned, borderline obsolete.  But they work just fine!  I fly a steam gauge airplane.

Comment: Live and learn, I guess. This question was the first time I've ever heard the term "steam cockpit." This is all making me feel really old.

Comment: @Terry I've never heard the term "steam cockpit" either, but "steam gauges" are a relatively common term now.

Comment: Well, before glass cockpits all instruments were of the "steam gauge" type, so there was no need to have a name for them.

Comment: There would never have been a reason to call them "steam" gauges until the emergence of glass cockpits. As a term to distinguish between them, "steam" would certainly suggest an image of round gauges with moving mechanical pointers commonly seen on steam-powered equipment. "Glass" cockpit seems a funny term... "steam" gauges have glass faces on them, just like digital displays do.

Comment: Skip's experience in the emergence of the term matches mine, in terms of arising only when glass cockpits became more and  more ubiquitous. It is indeed a (slightly) derogatory term but I am not sure who started it.  Might be neat trivia to know.

Comment: I just did a google books search on various combinations of "steam gauge" and  airplane from 1930-1980 and got no hits, so I too suspect that the term wasn’t coined until the advent of glass cockpits.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Probably not the first occurrance but in 1993 the Pilot Vehicle Interface document from the FAA mentions 'Older cockpits contained numerous "steam gauge" style indicators.'    http://bit.ly/2cXIbRq