# Are there any legal requirements concerning airline pilots and their watches?

Tags: faa-regulations, cockpit, airline-pilot

Are there any legal requirements concerning airline pilots and their watches? Do they have to be of any particular kind and are pilots required to wear one at all?

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21017/62)

Comment: Not worth an answer but the only thing I can think of is that it can't get in the way of operating the plane. So no Flavor Flav style -- um -- stuff.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Well, a wristwatch can't be used to sneak around the requirement that IFR requires a clock mounted in the aircraft, [FAR 91.205(d)(6)](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2010/march/16/shop-talk-aircraft-clocks).  A missing or inoperative clock isn't likely in a modern airliner.  As far as the FAA is concerned, a wristwatch is nothing more than jewelry.

Ages ago, a wristwatch may have helped with calculating fuel burn and range, but even then, it was a convenience rather than mandated equipment.

Comment: FWIW, I've had my PPL since the late '70s, and have never owned or worn a wristwatch.

Comment: BUT, if you do wear one it has to be a large, blingy, one that leaves no mistake as to your status as a cool dude pilot :)

Comment: A pity that we have no rear bumpers to proclaim, my other cessna is a porsche.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune - "My other plane is a Porsche-Mooney" may be more appropriate... :)